# Is it possible to scale the contents of an <iframe> without resizing the <iframe> itself?

Tags: css, iframe, scale, css-transforms

I'm using media queries to scale an `<iframe>` based on screen resolution: the `iframe` and its contents get smaller, as the screen gets smaller. Now, this seems alright on paper, but for some reason, as the `iframe`'s size decreases, it clips part of the content. I've tried going to the source file, and using media queries there, in hopes that the `<iframe>` would also include those; to no effect.
Is there any way to scale, or resize, the *contents* of an `<iframe>`, using CSS media queries, without resizing the `iframe` itself?

Comment: Is the Iframe YOUR content, or from another site?

Comment: It's from my site. As mentioned in the original question, I tried editing the CSS of the content's source to include media queries; that failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possible way to style any of the content within a iFrame, because it is pulling content directly from somewhere else and is not taking anything from your site into account.

If you are just trying to grab a few things from a page maybe you should look into PHP.